# Check if element returned by xpath is correct

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am making my first Python project.
I am trying to scrape a web page like this:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.mypage.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
table = tree.xpath('//table[@class="list"]')
```

However, I'm not sure if the table returned is correct.

Is there a way of checking the `html` content from the table?

If I try doing this:

```
print str(table)
```

I get this output, which is not very useful:

```
[<Element table at 0x10b20b6d8>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tostring()` to print raw HTML of the element :

```
from lxml import html

.....

html.tostring(table[0])
```